# How to convert a List[List[Long]] to a List[List[Int]]?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

What's the best way to convert a `List[List[Long]]` to a `List[List[Int]]` in Scala?

For example, given the following list of type `List[List[Long]]`

```
val l: List[List[Long]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
```

how can it be converted to `List[List[Int]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `l.map(_.map(_.toInt))` like so

```
val l: List[List[Long]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
l.map(_.map(_.toInt))
```

which should give

```
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `cats` lib for that and compose `List` functors

```
import cats.Functor
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data._

val l: List[List[Long]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))

Functor[List].compose[List].map(l)(_.toInt)
//or
Nested(l).map(_.toInt).value
```

and one more pure scala approach (not very safe, though)

```
val res:List[List[Int]] = l.asInstanceOf[List[List[Int]]]
```

Comment: Both of these look more complicated than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Tim author of the question requested "best way". Who knows what "best way" means)

Comment: You asked who knows what "best way" means: Occam's Razor is a highly regarded principle for deciding which of two solutions is better.

Comment: "better" is an abstract notion. The meaning is context dependent.

Comment: @xin you might have mentioned different approaches to achieve this... than best or better bogdan-vakulenko is right. be clear on what you are asking next time.

Answer (score 3):

Only if you are completely sure that you won't overflow the **Int**.

```
val l1: List[List[Long]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
val l2: List[List[Int]] = l1.map(list => list.map(long => long.toInt))
```

*(Basically, every time you want to transform a List into another List, use `map`)*.

Answer (score 1):

can be achieved with simple transformation on collection using `map` function.

`map` works by applying a function to each element in the list. in your case nested lists are there. so you need to apply `map` function 2 times like below example...

```
val x : List[List[Long]] = List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))   
println(x)

val y :List[List[Int]]= x.map(a => a.map(_.toInt))

println(y)
```

Output :

```
List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
List(List(11, 10, 11, 10, 11), List(8, 19, 24, 0, 2))
```